# How to change value of div String in jquery

Tags: jquery

This may be a simple question for all of you. But I am working hours and am not getting the right answer.

I have code like

```
var ss = "<div class='GridCellDiv' style='width: 68px;'>1000</div>";  
console.log(ss);  
$(ss).text("1001");  
console.log(ss);
```

Still the value is 1000. I even tired .html() but all in vain. 
Obviously my need is to change the text inside div

How to do the same. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `$(ss).text("1001");` you are creating a temp dom object with jQuery wrapper and is modifying its content, this will not update the original source in the `ss` variable.

If you want the updated content you need to get it from the created dom element reference.

You can do it like

```
var ss = "<div class='GridCellDiv' style='width: 68px;'>1000</div>";  
var $ss  = $(ss);
console.log($ss);  
$ss.text("1001");  
console.log($ss[0].outerHTML);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nq4s80w3/)

Comment: The problem is, this text is what gets applied inside a <tr>.I need to change the text insde div without disturbing the css

Comment: @Robert_Junior sorry, not clear.... can you explain it again... with the use case... if possible edit the fiddle to recreate your case

Comment: Ok. I have grid of values.But for the first row to make the rest of table rigid the plugin I have used has applied a div with css width[as above].

Ultimatly i need to change the cell value.So I need to change the div text value without removing css:width:68px

Comment: Ok the problem is solved with your solution.Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 2):

You do not modify the string `ss`. With `$(ss)` you create a jQuery object based on that HTML code, then you change its text, and then you discard it.

Have a look at this:

```
var ss = "<div class='GridCellDiv' style='width: 68px;'>1000</div>";  
console.log(ss);
ss = $(ss).text("1001");  
console.log(ss[0].outerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```js
var ss =  $(".GridCellDiv")
console.log(ss);  
ss.text("1001");  
console.log(ss);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='GridCellDiv' style='width: 68px;'>1000</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing like this?

```
$('.GridCellDiv').html('1001');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send your String to the jQuery function.
Once your String becomes a HTMLElement wrapped with all the nice jQuery methods, than you can access ones like `.text()` and operate directly to the Element.

```
var ss = $("<div class='GridCellDiv' style='width: 68px;'>1000</div>");   // jQuery ElementObject
console.log(ss);                // [object Object]...
$(ss).text("1001");
console.log( ss.text() );       // "1001"
console.log( ss[0].outerHTML ); // "<div class='GridCellDiv' style='width: 68px;'>1001</div>"
```